# Dynamic/Adaptive Gridview to have itemtemplates stretch using RelativePanel in Win10 XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, gridview, winrt-xaml

I would like to reproduce the News app in Win10 and have my ItemTemplate resize/stretch depending the size on my Window and also be able to move around depending on the size of the windows (so that this can work for Phone and Tablet apps).

I have tried using RelativePanel with a Listview but my items are not resizing, should I be trying to use a Gridview and work with VariableSizedGridView?

Does it look like this application is using 2 Gridview that are stack one on another with 2 different visual states depending on the size of the window?

Here are screenshot of the app and a video of the smooth effect that i would like to reproduce: 
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/k47ZXBmcfBWnd0dbp9M

Edit:

It looks like they used an ItemTemplateSelector to have a different style on the first two elements. but I am having issues getting my elements to stretch.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like they just used a bunch of ViewBox's and WrapGrids/Panels and set Min/Max sizes on objects to me.

Comment: Yes for me too, it looks like they used an ItemTemplateSelector to have a different style on the first two elements. but I am having issues getting my elements to stretch

Comment: Nah I doubt they even used an ItemTemplateSelector honestly, could probably do just the same thing with a proper layout with objects like your images in viewbox's and correct use of some wrapping panels, doesn't look too hard.